# Powershell Get-clipboard function not work in scheduler

Tags: excel, powershell, clipboard

$clp was empty when i run the following script by scheduler but i got result if i execute manually on Powershell ISE. Is Get-clipboard function not allowed in windows scheduler?

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Temp\ABC.xlsx')
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item("DATA")

$WorkSheet.activate()
$range1 = $WorkSheet.Range("A:D")
$range1.copy()

$clp = Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html | Select-Object -Skip 7 


$objExcel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

clipboard is a feature of interactive user session. it may not be available otherwise. you can copy cell values into variables instead.

Comment: The original purpose is to copy the table format from excel file to html code...

Comment: PowerShell will not let you run a session as an interactive user. PowerShell will always run in the user context who started, no matter where you started it from. This is a Windows security boundary. Unless you are using say PSExec in the mix, you'll need to rethink what you are doing here. Write to a file and then convert that to an HTML table.

Comment: Marco, if data conversion is the goal, there is no need to involve clipboard.